# Creating a Simple JAX-WS WebService in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-ws

I'm trying to create a simple web service in eclipse. First i created an empty java project and added the three following files in the src folder

1. Greeting.java

```java
package com.alfaisaliah;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public interface Greeting {
    @WebMethod
    String sayHello(String name);
}
```

2. GreetingImp.java

```java
package com.alfaisaliah;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface="com.alfaisaliah.Greeting")
public class GreetingImp implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

3. WSPublisher

```java
package com.alfaisaliah;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class WSPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/WS/Greeting", new GreetingImp());
    }
}
```

The tutorial I'm following doesn't specify any server to run the web service on! I'm wondering if I need to specify any server. I already have Tomcat v5.5 but am not using it in this example. Whenever I run this project as a java project I get some kind of error. Can anyone please help me identify where my problem is trying to run the web service. Here is the output of the eclipse console

```
Feb 26, 2012 12:01:00 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class com.alfaisaliah.jaxws.SayHello

Feb 26, 2012 12:01:00 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class com.alfaisaliah.jaxws.SayHelloResponse
```

Also when I run the project again it says that the address is already in use

```
Feb 26, 2012 12:01:00 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getRequestWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating request wrapper Class com.alfaisaliah.jaxws.SayHello

Feb 26, 2012 12:01:00 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.RuntimeModeler getResponseWrapperClass
INFO: Dynamically creating response wrapper bean Class com.alfaisaliah.jaxws.SayHelloResponse
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I would appreciate your help guys :)

Comment: The messages concerning creation of wrapper beans is OK. It basically a part of JAX-WS ability to generate WSDL on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this link out,

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_jaxws/

Above link gives step-by-step details for generating both web-service server and client.

You start with POJO, no annotation needed, JAX-WS runtime will take care after deployment on Tomcat server.

Answer (score 4):

> The tutorial i'm following doesn't specify any server to run the web
>   service on! I'm wondering if I need to specify any server.

You don't need a server with this code.
Your `main` in:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8081/WS/Greeting", new GreetingImp());
```

starts a light http server under the hood (available after JKD 1.6) and it deploys your web service handling all incoming/outgoing traffic.

The problem here is that you missed a step:
You have to generate the required artifacts using the `wsgen` tool (available in java).

Check out here: [JAX WS tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXWS3.html) for
`wsgen -d build -s build -classpath build
    helloservice.endpoint.Hello`
and read about `wsgen`.

To be honest I don't remember how you do it via Eclipse (actually I am not sure if this can work in Eclipse *automatically* without *you* needing to run `wsgen` yourself) but you can run it manually and just copy the generated artifacts in your project.

As for the

> Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

This is self-explanatory: Just use another port. 8081 is already used.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this out. Now I know the problem is not in the code or the server. I looked into the wsgen command tool and I understand most of the options and parameter; however, when I cd into the project folder and wsgen it says SEI is missing!!! I'm not sure if I should cd into the src folder or the bin folder of the project then apply wsgen? most of the tutorials out there don't specify that, they just go with the command and options. Thanks

Comment: OK...I found out how to use the wsgen to generate the artifacts and wsdl...I also changed the port to 8088. Where should i put these files in the project hierarchy?

Comment: Under their corresponding package